# keymaps : strings as usual

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

In the keymaps manpage, section ABBREVIATIONS :

```
strings as usual
Defines the usual values of the strings (but not the keys they are bound to).
```

In which file are these usual definitions ?

Comment: Reading the rest of the section, you'll see that dumpkeys gives what information is available, but comments that there's really no complete description available..

Comment: Yes, but it does not give me the usual values of the string. In my own keymap file, I add two lines : strings as usual and string F10 = "abcde" (Rq : keycode 68 = F10). When I hit F10 key, abcde is printed as expected. When I hit F1 key, A is printed. I suppose it is due to "strings as usual" but where I could find the list of *usual* values.